# Javascript get current month name and range

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

is there some feature in JS that can get me current month name ? For instance when I want to get date range I do it like this:

```
 var startDate = ConvertToNewDateFormat(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0));
    var endDate = ConvertToNewDateFormat(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1));
```

But how can I get the current month name... Like for instance today is May, and I'd like to get it in form of string "May"...

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: You might be able to use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). What browsers do you have to support?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in<sup>1</sup>, you have to use your own array:

```
// Somewhere reusable
var monthNames = [
    "January",
    "February",
    // ...
    "December"
];

// When you need the name
var name = montNames(theDate.getMonth());
```

...or use a library like MomentJS or similar. **Update**: You've said you're using MomentJS, so to get the month name you can use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```
monthName = moment(theDate).format("MMMM");
```

Or you can use [the localization information](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/):

```
monthName = moment.months()[theDate.getMonth()];
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For *short* month names, you can usually isolate it from the result of `toString`, but that's not in the spec, the format varies from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine and between locales (for good reason!), and they're usually in short form ("Jan" rather than "January"). But I wouldn't.

Comment: I have included momentJS into my project... Can you show me an example with moment?

Comment: @perkes456: It's right there in [the documentation for `format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/): The `MMMM` format specifier. There's also [`moment.months()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) to get the array of month names for Moment's current locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date.prototype.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) to get the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year)

```js
const date = new Date()
const monthsArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
const month = monthsArray[date.getMonth()]

console.log(month)
```

Also you can use [Date.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to get a string with a language sensitive representation of this date passing as second parameter options `{ month: 'long' }`:

```js
const date = new Date()
const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })

console.log(month)
```